# Session is expiring after 20 mins in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set Session time of 60 mins in Asp.Net MVC but session is expiring after 20 mins. Following is my code in Web.config:

```
<system.web>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" cookieless="false"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

is there missing something??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/10/session-timeout-problem-in-aspnet.html

Comment: Try to increase the idel-timeout setting in Application Pool in IIS. By default  it's recycled after 20 idle minutes

Comment: I had deployed my Asp.Net application on remote server

Comment: @RAKHI so is it a shared hosting?

Comment: @Webruster yes, it is shared hosting

Comment: @RAKHI Shared hosts sometimes have unusually frequent application pool recycles. This could result in your sessions getting wiped out if you're using in-process session state. You can work around this by moving your session state out of process. Since it's a shared host, I'm guessing your only option really is to keep your session state in a database.Check out the MSDN page on [Session-State modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) for details on how to do this.